# Accessing Expression Engine fetch_action_id function in a Module CP's view file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, expressionengine

I am writing a script using AJAX in JQuery that takes an action_id from exp_actions as the destination URL for the method I need to execute in my mcp file. The reference is made statically. Can the ACT value be found by making a PHP call in the view in a way similar to:

`$aid =$this->EE->cp->fetch_action_id('Class_name', 'method_name');` ?

My page currently looks this way:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').change(function(e){
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        console.log(data);
        $.post(
            <? echo'http://ourwebsite.com/ee/admin.php?ACT=44&id=4 ,';?>
            data,
            function() {
                console.log(this);
            } 
        )
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer to my question on the expressionengine forums. For those curious, the link is below. Thanks for the help :)

http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/171401/#986831

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using that script in a template or a snippet, you could make a call to your addon instead, returning the needed URL:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').change(function(e){
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        console.log(data);
        $.post(
            '{exp:your_addon:method_for_getting_action_id_url}',
            data,
            function() {
                console.log(this);
            } 
        )
    });
});
```

Comment: For the purposes of my page, I am hoping to do this from the view file of this module or within the mcp file. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, why not just pass the info as dato to the view you are returning?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an ajax request in the CP, you just need to request the cp url:

```
/system/index.php?S=0&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=my_module&method=my_method
```